# Why is this hmac digest different on Python 2.7 and Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, hmac, hashlib

I'm trying to move a project from Python 2.7 to Python 3.7 and run into an issue with an hmac digest. Running the following code produces 2 different results

```
import hmac, hashlib
print(hmac.new(bytes([]), bytes([]), hashlib.sha1).hexdigest())
```

On Python 2.7: `1bd590e48bea8f0c8cc70602bc55d317c3de7c52`

On Python 3.7: `fbdb1d1b18aa6c08324b7d64b71fb76370690e1d`

Why are these two results different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.7, `bytes()` and `bytes([])` are both interpreted as `b''`.

In Python 2.7, `bytes()` is interpreted as `''` which is roughly equivalent to `b''` in Python 3.7.

However, Python 2.7 interprets `bytes([])` as `'[]'`.

That is the source of the difference.  If you use `bytes()` or `b''` instead of `bytes([])`, you should get the same result in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

In 2.7 `bytes([])` is type str while in 3.7 `bytes([])` is type bytes.

If you sub in something like `b"hello"` for both the key and message in both 2.7 and 3.7 you will get the same hash back.